How can I calculate age from date of birth
I have a Date of birth field that I want to automatically calculate and display the user's age as he enters his date of birth which must be in the format of yyyy-mm-dd
I tried the logic but I've only managed to get the years. I'm still unable to calculate the months and days of age from user's date of birth.

Provide a code of what you are trying.

Be aware that counting the months and days can be open for interpretation. If the birth date is 28/02/2024 and today we would be 28/02/2025, would that be exactly 1 year? Or 1 year and a day? What if we move both dates one day forward to get 29/02/2024 and 01/03/2025... does that change the answer? Why? I hope you can see that this needs a very precise specification of what you expect.

Do you need the complete years from a birth date?
